# How do I insert a custom post type query after a certain number of recent posts and then resume recent posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query

Example:

- 4 most recent regular posts
- 6 posts queried from custom post type
- 8 regular posts ( most recent posts with a 4 post offset so that it's a continuation of the first four posts on the page)
- pagination (for regular/recent posts, not custom post type)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a loop with 12 posts per page and after printing 4 posts I'd call another loop with 6 custom posts. Then go back and print the last 8 posts of current page.

```
<?php

    $index = 1;

    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged));

    if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

        <article>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </article>

    <?php

        if($index == 4){
            $custom = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'CUSTOM-POST-TYPE', 'posts_per_page' => 6));
            if ($pcustom->have_posts()) : while ($pcustom->have_posts()) : $pcustom->the_post(); ?>

                <article>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </article>
    <?php
            endwhile; endif;
        }

        $index++;

    endwhile; endif;


    wp_pagenavi($posts);

?>
```